# Girls are Mean!

Tags: word, visual, story, knowledge

[image]

---

> Can you help poor little Benjamin fix his homework paper before he submits it?
>   He needs to know what words to put back into his paper.
>
> ---

### Transcript:

> `Little Brothers` are Our Friends
>
> People usually think that `brothers` are pigs, but they are wrong. They aren't wild pigs at all but are actually members of the "`neighbor's`" family that originated in South `Jersey.`
>
> Some people say that `brothers` are "cute,” or "adorable," but they are generally considered rather ugly animals. They have a good sense of smell but less-than-perfect eyesight. They have a peculiar, disgusting odor about them, which is why some people refer to them as `"Turd Burglars." The` smell comes from a scent gland on their `butt` and other members of the herd will rub each
>   other's scent gland to identify `the dorks` from different `n`erds.
>
> `Brothers` are slowly becoming used to the fact that they live close to humans.  If people try and approach them they will simply leave the area, but if provoked and threatened they've been known to defend themselves with their long, sharp `pointy heads.`
>
> The lifespan of a  `dork`  is about 8 years, but, in captivity some have been known to live to as many as `8.5` years old. They often travel in herds of 20 to protect themselves from their natural predators, which include coyotes, mountain lions, and `smarter big sisters.`
>
> Living so close to human society, `the asshats` are often found walking through suburban areas, digging through people's garbages and making general nuisances of themselves.
>
> The word `“Brother”` comes from other languages and could be said to mean “Wild Mountaineer,” `or “Wad-Face.”`

Comment: There are some discrepancies between the image and the transcript.  **neighbor's** vs. `neighbors`, **Burglars** vs. `Burglers`, **butt** vs. `butts`, **pointy** vs. `pointy heads`, **smarter** vs. `smarter big sisters`.  Not sure if these are part of the puzzle or just transcription errors.

Comment: neighbors, Burglers, and butt were (inconsequential) transcription errors, now fixed, Thanks! Pointy and Smarter were cases where the 'whiteout' was only used to cover the original text, showing the length of the original word(s).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This essay is about the...

> **[Peccary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peccary)** [OP EDIT: "Javelina," fitting the translation at the end]

Transcript:

> **Peccaries** are Our Friends
>
>  People usually think that **Peccaries** are pigs, but they are wrong. They aren't wild pigs at all but are actually members of the **Tayassuidae** family that originated in South **America**.
>
>  
> Some people say that **Peccaries** are "cute,” or "adorable," but they are generally considered rather ugly animals. They have a good sense of smell but less-than-perfect eyesight. They have a peculiar, disgusting odor about them, which is why some people refer to them as "**skunk pigs**." The smell comes from a scent gland on their **backs** and other members of the herd will rub each other's scent gland to identify **Peccaries** from different **h**erds.
>
> **Peccaries** are slowly becoming used to the fact that they live close to humans. If people try and approach them they will simply leave the area, but if provoked and threatened they've been known to defend themselves with their long, sharp **tusks**.
>
>  
> The lifespan of a **Peccary** is about 8 years, but, in captivity some have been known to live to as many as **24** years old. They often travel in herds of 20 to protect themselves from their natural predators, which include coyotes, mountain lions, and **jaguars**.
>
>  
> Living so close to human society, the **Peccaries** are often found walking through suburban areas, digging through people's garbages and making general nuisances of themselves.
>
>  
> The word “**?**” comes from other languages and could be said to mean “Wild Mountaineer,” or “**?**.”

Comment: Nice answer - I've just put in a link to the relevant animal, feel free to edit that out if you wish.

Comment: The edits ("little", "brother") seem to have a connection to [pequeninos](http://enderverse.wikia.com/wiki/Pequeninos), a fictional pig-like species from the Ender series. May be entirely a coincidence?

Comment: @humfuzz You're a speaker for the dead, aren't you! Just a coincidence, though.

Comment: +1 and Good Answer! The only reason I would have to not call this 100% correct is that {answer} doesn't come close to translating to "Wild Mountaineer” (that I can see). The reason I added the last paragraph at all was to be unambiguous.

Comment: Seems like it's "wniryvan"? (rot13)

Comment: @KyleMiller I accidentally googled instead of (rot13)ing your (correct) guess and got something that "smells like teen spirit." ;)